# Stop Netgear Orbi from calling home

Tags: networking, privacy

Since I have my own DNS and I monitor queries placed from my devices I saw that after buying the netgear orbi I'm flooded with DNS-resolves for netgear.com

How can I stop my netgear from calling home?

The most obvious thing would be to block all netgear queries but I'm afraid that this may breaks other things (or I forget it and in a few years get mad because I can't access their website).

Comment: Do you have an advanced firewall? Add more information to the question, all devices & topology would be good.

Comment: not behind the orbi. Orbi is the device that faces the internet. I'm also looking for ways on disabling it on the orbi itself; just blocking connections wouldn't be a problem.