# What is a software doing when “calling home” or “phoning home”?

Tags: networking, privacy

I saw “calling home” mentioned in several places but I can't find a clear definition.

References:

- [Stop Netgear Orbi from **calling home** (SuperUser)](https://superuser.com/q/1400911/267546)
- [It's easy to run Windows 10 without any **calling home** at all (HackerNews)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10802086)
- [Windows 10 still **phones home**, even when ordered not to do so (ExtremeTech)](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/212160-windows-10-still-phones-home-even-when-ordered-not-to-do-so)
- [Does Unity still **phone home** at runtime? (Unity Forum)](https://forum.unity.com/threads/does-unity-still-phone-home-at-runtime.1163186/)

It looks like it refers to some telemetry sent to the vendors.

The names “calling home” and “phoning home” are misleading, at first I thought that it was a feature to perform an audio call to the owner's house.

What is the call in this instance? What is the home? How was this term created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling home means that the software makes contact with a server from the manufacturer in order to tell the software developer that their software is run on a computer.

This can be done by verifying a license, or being done for stats and other things.

Its a reference to the movie ET to phone home, in order to get picked up, but rather than being picked up, the "phonecall" is made to just know that you are there.

Comment: Note that the software *may* give a lot more information to "home" than just usage statistics and error reports. Scary amounts of information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoning_home

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote and other things.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now that you explained the ET reference.